# How do i fix this MySQL function so that the “This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA” error is avoided?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have this function

```
RETURN ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(lat1))*SIN(RADIANS(lat2))+COS(RADIANS(lat1))*COS(RADIANS(lat2))*COS(RADIANS(lon2-lon1)))*6371;
```

And i get the error

This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA”.

How do i fix this such that the error does not occur?

Comment: With binary logging, you have to add DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA to the definition of the function. That is the part that is infront of your code but not included in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CREATE FUNCTION error "This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920386/create-function-error-this-function-has-none-of-deterministic-no-sql-or-reads)